# List informations about SQL Servers through linked servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I'm finding out information from other instances through linked servers using the `SERVERPROPERTY`. Unfortunately the `SERVERPROPERTY` relates to the server from which I am now running the query.

Can you help me?

Query:

```
declare @instance_name nvarchar(50)
declare @command nvarchar(max)

declare instance_name_cursor cursor for
     select name 
     from msdb.sys.servers 
     where product = 'SQL Server'

open instance_name_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM instance_name_cursor INTO @instance_name

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    select @command = 'declare @osversion nvarchar(50)

set @osversion = (select 
case
when windows_release = ''10.0'' then ''Windows Server 2016''
when windows_release = ''6.3'' then ''Windows Server 2012 R2''
when windows_release = ''6.2'' then ''Windows Server 2012''
when windows_release = ''6.1'' then ''Windows Server 2008 R2''
when windows_release = ''6.0'' then ''Windows Server 2008''
end
from sys.dm_os_windows_info )

insert into mydatabase.dbo.sql_server_info

select SERVERPROPERTY (''MachineName''),SERVERPROPERTY (''ProductVersion''),
SERVERPROPERTY (''Edition''),SERVERPROPERTY (''ProductLevel''),
cpu_count,(physical_memory_kb /1024),
(select maximum FROM ['+@instance_name+'].master.sys.configurations 
where configuration_id=1544),@osversion
from ['+@instance_name+'].master.sys.dm_os_sys_info'

     exec (@command)

     FETCH NEXT FROM instance_name_cursor INTO @instance_name
end

CLOSE instance_name_cursor
DEALLOCATE instance_name_cursor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the `SERVERPROPERTY()` function on the linked server, which you can do using `OPENQUERY`, as a simple example:

```
SELECT  MachineName
FROM    OPENQUERY([LinkedServer], 'SELECT MachineName = SERVERPROPERTY (''MachineName'')') x;
```

Then it is just a case of adjusting your query slightly to deal with this, so removing the cursor for demonstration terms you might have something like:

```
DECLARE @instance_name nvarchar(50) = 'LinkedServer';
DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @commandBase NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    'SELECT MachineName = SERVERPROPERTY (''''MachineName''''),
            ProductVersion = SERVERPROPERTY (''''ProductVersion''''),
            Edition = SERVERPROPERTY (''''Edition''''),
            ProductLevel = SERVERPROPERTY (''''ProductLevel''''),
            Maximum = (SELECT Maximum FROM master.sys.configurations WHERE configuration_id = 1544),
            OSVersion = CASE
                            WHEN wi.windows_release =''''10.0'''' THEN ''''Windows Server 2016''''
                            WHEN wi.windows_release = ''''6.3'''' THEN ''''Windows Server 2012 R2''''
                            WHEN wi.windows_release = ''''6.2'''' THEN ''''Windows Server 2012''''
                            WHEN wi.windows_release = ''''6.1'''' THEN ''''Windows Server 2008 R2''''
                            WHEN wi.windows_release = ''''6.0'''' THEN ''''Windows Server 2008''''
                        END
    FROM    master.sys.dm_os_sys_info AS si
            CROSS JOIN master.sys.dm_os_windows_info AS wi;';


SET @Command = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(', QUOTENAME(@instance_name), ', ''', @CommandBase, ''');');

INSERT mydatabase.dbo.sql_server_info (<Columns>)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Command;
```

Then it is just a case of slotting this inside your cursor.